# JTree неверное отображение

Tags: java, swing

Создаю отдельный класс расширяющий JTree. Для примера решил попробовать из [туториала](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#create)

Вот класс:

```
public class Tree extends JTree  {
private DefaultMutableTreeNode rootNode;
    private DefaultTreeModel treeModel;
    public Tree() {
        rootNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Root Node");
        createNodes(rootNode);
                treeModel = new DefaultTreeModel(rootNode, true);
    setRootVisible(true);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 400));
setMaximumSize(new Dimension(250, 400));

}
    private void createNodes(DefaultMutableTreeNode top) {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode category= null;
        DefaultMutableTreeNode book= null;
    category = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Books for Java Programmers");
    top.add(category);

    //original Tutorial
    book = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("The Java Tutorial: A Short Course on the Basics");
    category.add(book);

    //Tutorial Continued
    book = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("The Java Tutorial Continued: The Rest of the JDK");
    category.add(book);

    //JFC Swing Tutorial
    book = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("The JFC Swing Tutorial: A Guide to Constructing GUIs");
    category.add(book);

    //...add more books for programmers...

    category = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Books for Java Implementers");
    top.add(category);

    //VM
    book = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("The Java Virtual Machine Specification");
    category.add(book);

    //Language Spec
    book = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("The Java Language Specification");
    category.add(book);
}

}
```

При создании экземпляра этого класса, почему-то во фрейме дефолтное дерево(Jtree>Colors>Sports>Food), не пойму в чём дело?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Покажите лучше код, где добавляете и создаете дерево на форме. В конструктор надо передавать модель.

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode top = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("The Java Series");
createNodes(top); 
tree = new JTree(top);'
```

В общем, там так и написано.

Comment: То есть, получается, мне надо, отдельно создать модель и передать её в конструктор?

Comment: ааа, всё понял )) незнал - что нужно в конструктор, обязательно модель передавать...
благодарю!

Comment: Не обязательно в конструктор. Можно засунуть модель через <a href="http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html#setModel%28javax.swing.tree.TreeModel%29">setModel</a>. Вообще, приучайтесь листать доку. Используйте JTree, так хоть вступление к классу прочтите. Там текста с гулькин нос, а польза большая.

Comment: Спасибо, setModel опробую.
Просто поторопился и пропустил очевидное...